# Table not centering in page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, scalebox

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %
\linespread{1.5} % one-and-a-half spacing; 1.6 for double spacing
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % Ajusta margen hoja
\usepackage{float} % Permite opción float en Figures para las que querés fijar en una página
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngpage}  % Permite ajustar margenes para tablas específicas
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
      \caption{Regressions with positive trade flows. Dependent variable: trade flows (log)}
        \scalebox{0.6}{
        \begin{tabular}{p{110}ccccccc}
        \toprule
              & (1)   & (2)   & (3)   & (4)   & (5)   & (6)   & (7) \\
                  \midrule
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        GDP origin (log) & 1.027*** & 1.026*** & 1.017*** & 1.006*** & 1.031*** & 1.035*** & 1.025*** \\
              & (768.36) & (768.44) & (763.19) & (728.81) & (742.00) & (744.59) & (735.26) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        GDP destination (log) & 0.859*** & 0.858*** & 0.850*** & 0.850*** & 0.872*** & 0.876*** & 0.866*** \\
              & (672.51) & (672.43) & (667.15) & (641.06) & (654.84) & (657.39) & (647.66) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        Distance (log) & -1.218*** & -1.160*** & -1.049*** & -1.058*** & -1.027*** & -1.024*** & -1.021*** \\
              & (-359.45) & (-315.65) & (-268.14) & (-269.71) & (-263.32) & (-262.83) & (-263.03) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 for contiguity &       & 0.705*** & 0.674*** & 0.679*** & 0.496*** & 0.457*** & 0.433*** \\
              &       & (40.36) & (38.76) & (39.10) & (28.63) & (26.39) & (25.06) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 for free trade agreement in force &       &       & 1.137*** & 1.101*** & 1.073*** & 1.057*** & 1.074*** \\
              &       &       & (79.62) & (76.90) & (75.56) & (74.52) & (75.90) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 if origin is GATT/WTO &       &       &       & 0.210*** & 0.189*** & 0.193*** & 0.190*** \\
              &       &       &       & (31.70) & (28.70) & (29.41) & (29.07) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 if destination is GATT/WTO &       &       &       & 0.0428*** & 0.0210** & 0.0229*** & 0.0199** \\
              &       &       &       & (6.53) & (3.23) & (3.53) & (3.07) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 for common official of primary language &       &       &       &       & 0.782*** & 0.632*** & 0.549*** \\
              &       &       &       &       & (103.79) & (76.99) & (66.17) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 for common legal origin &       &       &       &       &       & 0.296*** & 0.263*** \\
              &       &       &       &       &       & (45.26) & (40.30) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        1 if current or past colonial link &       &       &       &       &       &       & 1.093*** \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       & (60.30) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        Constant & -4.008*** & -4.525*** & -5.327*** & -5.274*** & -6.007*** & -6.176*** & -6.061*** \\
              & (-65.52) & (-72.48) & (-84.65) & (-83.84) & (-95.71) & (-98.38) & (-96.79) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
            Year FE & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
            Observations & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}%
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \small
          \item Note: t statistics in parentheses.  * p$<$0.05  ** p$<$0.01 *** p$<$0.001
        \end{tablenotes}    
      \label{tab:tab1}%
    \end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't show the document class, so we don't know how wide the page might be.  if the table is wider than the defined page width, it will not center.  to make it possible to diagnose the problem, please provide a minimal compilable file, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  then we won't need to rely on our oft-overused and inconsistent crystal balls.,

Comment: What does `p{110}` mean? I guess there is a unit missing like `p{110mm}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change `\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}` to `\usepackage{threeparttable}`.

But there is still the problem with the line:

```
    \begin{tabular}{p{110}ccccccc} % <==================================110
```

Change it for example to

```
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}ccccccc} % <==================================110
```

Then your table is small enouph to be centered on the page as the following MWE shows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %

\linespread{1.5} % one-and-a-half spacing; 1.6 for double spacing
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % Ajusta margen hoja
\usepackage{float} % Permite opción float en Figures para las que querés fijar en una página
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngpage}  % Permite ajustar margenes para tablas específicas

%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % <=========================================

\usepackage{booktabs} % <===============================================


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
  \caption{Regressions with positive trade flows. Dependent variable: trade flows (log)}
    \label{tab:tab1}%
    \scalebox{0.6}{
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}ccccccc} % <==================================110
    \toprule
          & (1)   & (2)   & (3)   & (4)   & (5)   & (6)   & (7) \\
              \midrule
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    GDP origin (log) & 1.027*** & 1.026*** & 1.017*** & 1.006*** & 1.031*** & 1.035*** & 1.025*** \\
          & (768.36) & (768.44) & (763.19) & (728.81) & (742.00) & (744.59) & (735.26) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    GDP destination (log) & 0.859*** & 0.858*** & 0.850*** & 0.850*** & 0.872*** & 0.876*** & 0.866*** \\
          & (672.51) & (672.43) & (667.15) & (641.06) & (654.84) & (657.39) & (647.66) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Distance (log) & -1.218*** & -1.160*** & -1.049*** & -1.058*** & -1.027*** & -1.024*** & -1.021*** \\
          & (-359.45) & (-315.65) & (-268.14) & (-269.71) & (-263.32) & (-262.83) & (-263.03) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 for contiguity &       & 0.705*** & 0.674*** & 0.679*** & 0.496*** & 0.457*** & 0.433*** \\
          &       & (40.36) & (38.76) & (39.10) & (28.63) & (26.39) & (25.06) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 for free trade agreement in force &       &       & 1.137*** & 1.101*** & 1.073*** & 1.057*** & 1.074*** \\
          &       &       & (79.62) & (76.90) & (75.56) & (74.52) & (75.90) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 if origin is GATT/WTO &       &       &       & 0.210*** & 0.189*** & 0.193*** & 0.190*** \\
          &       &       &       & (31.70) & (28.70) & (29.41) & (29.07) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 if destination is GATT/WTO &       &       &       & 0.0428*** & 0.0210** & 0.0229*** & 0.0199** \\
          &       &       &       & (6.53) & (3.23) & (3.53) & (3.07) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 for common official of primary language &       &       &       &       & 0.782*** & 0.632*** & 0.549*** \\
          &       &       &       &       & (103.79) & (76.99) & (66.17) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 for common legal origin &       &       &       &       &       & 0.296*** & 0.263*** \\
          &       &       &       &       &       & (45.26) & (40.30) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1 if current or past colonial link &       &       &       &       &       &       & 1.093*** \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       & (60.30) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Constant & -4.008*** & -4.525*** & -5.327*** & -5.274*** & -6.007*** & -6.176*** & -6.061*** \\
          & (-65.52) & (-72.48) & (-84.65) & (-83.84) & (-95.71) & (-98.38) & (-96.79) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        Year FE & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
        Observations & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 & 624145 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}%
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item Note: t statistics in parentheses.  * p$<$0.05  ** p$<$0.01 *** p$<$0.001
    \end{tablenotes}    
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

I suggest to not use `\scalebox{0.6}` for the table, if possible ...

Please see that I moved the command `\label` after command `\caption` where it belongs ... And I added the missing package `booktabs` to the MWE.